# Add alternating rowcolor to Angular Material Table with expandable rows

Tags: angular, angular-material

Starting for the Angular Material example for a table with expandable Row (https://stackblitz.com/angular/ybxxqkoqknl?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.css) I would like to add alternating rowcolors to that table.
The standard solution (as shown below) is not working however, because of the expanded rows being present in the table (with height = 0).
Could there be any alternative solution to make alternating rowcolors possible in this table?

```
.mat-row:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #eee;
}
.mat-row:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this CSS stylesheet. By default, all the rows (included detailed rows) will be `background-color: white`.

For every third & forth row (even row with its detailed row), `background-color: #eee`.

```
.mat-row {
  background-color: white;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(4n-1), .mat-row:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pb6lzn)

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 new classes in the `css` file that look like this:

```css
.odd-row {
  background-color: white;
}

.even-row {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

and in the template, where you render the row, I added the classes based on the index of the data item being rendered:

```html
  <tr mat-row 
    *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay; let i = dataIndex;"
    class="example-element-row"
    [class.odd-row]="i % 2"
    [class.even-row]="!(i % 2)"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` with a formula to color the relevant rows:

```
.mat-row:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: red;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

There is a cycle of 4 to the next relevant row, and you specify the starting offset after the `+`.

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkhxmg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.css

Answer (score 0):

under Angular 15 MDC and above, change to:

```
.mat-mdc-row:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: red;
}

.mat-mdc-row:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: blue;
}
```